# Set a same box size of different figures in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot figures with the same box size inside the figure in python matplotlib. Basically, I want to make the height and width of axes the same from one figure to another (please see the red arrows in below figures)

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(3.5,3))
axes.plot([0.1,0.2,0.3])
axes.set_ylabel(ylabel='Y',weight='bold')
axes.set_xlabel('X',weight='bold')
plt.show()
```

[image: red arrows: a is width, b is height]

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(3.5,3))
axes.plot([1,2,3])
axes.set_ylabel(ylabel='Y',weight='bold')
axes.set_xlabel('X',weight='bold')
plt.show()
```

[image: red arrows: c is width, d is height]

I want to make sure that **a=c** and **b=d**
I will be very grateful if you can help me

Comment: Doesn't this happen by default (except when you'd use `plt.tight_layout()` or `plt.savefig(..., bbox_inches='tight')`)? If you're working inside a Jupyter notebook, it would be a bit harder to suppress the tight layout.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 8))
# rect = (left, bottom, width, height) in relative figure-units
# (e.g. in the range 0-1)
ax = f.add_axes(rect=(.1,.1,.8,.8))
```